# Unity - How to give some flexibility to colliders

Tags: unity-game-engine, collider

Hi  I'am new to Unity and I was trying to implement a game using tetris blocks.

The game's goal is to build the highest tower before it collapses. However there is a problem in my implementation which is seen in the picture below.

I achieve the building a tower task by activating the rigidbody gravityscale when it collides with something. With that way it can collapse after touching somewhere not before. But I want to have the flexibility of some collisions. In the situation seen in the picture below, that 'T' block will collide with the point in the **red circle** before landing safely and gravityscale of the rigidbody will be set. So it will drop but I don't want it to happen becasue the collision area is too small. I want to make it land safely with some flexibility.

I tried to make colliders' size 0.9 but that just disrupts the scale of the world.

Can I do something like this :
If collision happens, check collision area and if the area is lower than lets say 0.1, do not trigger rigidbody gravityscale.

[image: TetroTower]

Comment: [Rigidbody2D.freezeRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-freezeRotation.html) to freeze z rotation and keep all the shapes "ortho" so that you can dodge the problem?

Comment: @rustyBucketBay if i freeze the z rotation, they will **never** rotate and the game will be useless. Tower will be collapsable, I just want to add some flexibility to it not to destroy whole mechanics. And I don't know what you mean by "ortho" as a newbie :)

Answer (score 0):

what about using capsulle collider 2D with small radius?